# Waiting for a 3rd party thread to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to call a 3rd party code that optionally starts a new thread, performs some processing, and then calls a different method on my object. What I need is wait for the 3rd party processing to be finished, then return from the original method. In other words, I have a class like this (C#):

```
class MyClass: IThirdPartyInterface {
    void MyMethod() {
        //some preprocessing
        //call a 3rd party static method
        ThirdParty.DoSomething(this);
     }
    void FinishedProcessing() {
        //some postprocessing
        //???
    }
}
```

I want to modify MyMethod so that it return only after the thread that started in DoSomething has finished its execution and called the FinishedProcessing method. Since the thread is started by the third party code, I don't have access to it, so I cannot use Thread.Join here. So, what do I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an System.Threading.AutoResetEvent, it would be like this:

```
class MyClass: IThirdPartyInterface {
    AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    void MyMethod() {
        ThirdParty.DoSomething(this);
        _event.WaitOne();
    }
    void FinishedProcessing() {
        _event.Set();
    }
}
```

If the thread continues running after your FinishedProcessing method is called by the 3rdparty class, it would be a little diferent:

```
class MyClass: IThirdPartyInterface {
    AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Thread _thread;
    void MyMethod() {
        ThirdParty.DoSomething(this);
        _event.WaitOne();
        _thread.Join();
    }
    void FinishedProcessing() {
        _thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        _event.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that's missing here is that you have to initialize the _event variable to new AutoResetEvent(false)

Answer (score 0):

Make your MyMethod() async and then run thirdparty method inside your custom await method, moething like this:

```
private async void MyMethod()
{
    var result = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync();
}

public async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync()
{
    await ThirdParty.DoSomething(this);
    return "Finished";
}
```

Comment: Won't work, as he explained DoSomething invokes a new thread and return. He wants to wait the thread to finish.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, I was to keep the 3.5 compatibility if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If ThirdParty.DoSomething does not support async pattern
you can use additional proxy with finalizer.
But it could affect application performance like a "while(myBoolFlag){}".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var m = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            list.Add(m);
            new Thread(Start).Start(m);

            if (i > 0 && (i % 10) == 0)
                for (int j = i - 10; j < i; j++)
                {
                    list[j].WaitOne(1000);// wait signal
                    GC.Collect(); //force finalizer
                    A.Print();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Start(object obj)
    {
        new A(obj as ManualResetEvent, null);
    }
}

public class A : IThirdPartyInterface
{
    public static long time1;
    public static long count1;

    private DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    private ManualResetEvent _stop;
    private IThirdPartyInterface _origin;
    public A(ManualResetEvent stop, IThirdPartyInterface origin)
    {
        _stop = stop;
        _origin = origin;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count1);
        Interlocked.Add(ref time1, (long)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);
        _stop.Set(); //send signal
    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.Write("\r" + A.time1 + "\\" + A.count1 + "    ");
        if (A.count1 != 0)
            Console.Write((A.time1 / A.count1).ToString());
    }
}
```